# React Hooks : UseRef not recognizing Event from Material UI Select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

I'm using React Hooks.I am trying to trigger a onclick event using useRef.

```
    const component1: React.FC<Props> = props {
      const node =useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

      const ClickListener = UseCallback((e:any)=>{
        if(node.current.contains(e.target))
         console.log("Event Contained");
        else console.log("Event not Contained");
      },[]);

      return (
        <div ref={node} onClick={ClickListener}>
         <FormControl>
           <InputLabel>{text}</InputLabel>
           <Select> {contents} </Select>
         </FormControl>
        </div>
      );
    };
```

I have this Component1 called by componentX and componentY.

The above code is failing to recognise onclick event on a componentX's node when componentY's select menu is opened.

Only after closing ComponentY's select menu and clicking again on ComponentX currently recognises the event.
Any Suggestions on why itsn't recognized.I am using Material UI's select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use callback ref.

Quoting from API doc:

> Keep in mind that useRef doesn’t notify you when its content changes.
>   Mutating the .current property doesn’t cause a re-render. If you want
>   to run some code when React attaches or detaches a ref to a DOM node,
>   you may want to use a [callback ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-measure-a-dom-node) instead.

**Edit**

Sorry to lead you in wrong direction. My suggestion to use callback ref is not correct for your code.

Your callbacks are working correctly and are able to use the div ref properly.
The reason you feel your callback is not working when Select in other component is opened is that Select uses mouse capture to detect click outside the pop-up.
So when your drop-down is open, click on other component div does not reach that div at all, it is consumed by Select. Subsequent click works well.
This is the case not only with your component but with any other element in the dom.

See: https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-star-k430x

Comment: Thanks! On using callbackref as ```<div ref={ClickListener} onClick={ClickListener}> ```shows following error Type '(e: any, node: HTMLDivElement) => void' is not assignable to type 'string | ((instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLDivElement> | null | undefined'.Any suggestions on where I am wrong using Call back ref.

Comment: yes, select's mouse event isnt allowing me to achieve this. I tried with mouseclick,mouseenter and mouseleave options, yet it behaves the same.Any insights on alternative approach?

Comment: Replacing Material UI select with custom dropdown helped.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `node` in the dependancy list to the useCallback method.
Otherwise, the `node` which refers to `null` while defining the `ClickListener` is not updated.

Go through the [docs - useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback). useCallback avoids redefining the function every time the component function is called. So any global variables inside the function definition has to be listed in dependancies array, so that react will redefine the function when ever the dependancies change.

```
 const ClickListener =UseCallback((e:any)=>{
    if(node.current.contains(e.target))
    console.log("Event Contained");
    else console.log("Event not Contained");
    },[node]);
```

Comment: Thanks! but it still behaves the same way after adding the dependancy.